# Is it possible to create Docker Linux Containers from .net framework 4.6 web app?

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-image

I have a .net web application which reefer .net core 2.1 assemblies.(shown in below image).

[image]

But TargetFramework of the project is still .net Framework 4.6.
[image]

I want to create a Linux Docker image from this project. Is it possible to do as the project it is now or should I upgrade the project in to .net core?

Please help.

Comment: first convert project to .netCore. There are no images for .netFramework that can be used to run your app in docker environments, so u need to convert to .net core. Other than your .csproj file, i'm sure most of your code will not require any changes except for a few classes/namespaces which may need a couple of tweaks or new nuget references.

Comment: Thanks Gerryc for quick answer. When I google around I found this and made me think that images with .net framework is possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/net-core-net-framework-containers/

Comment: .net framework wld only apply if you will be using Windows containers, but u mentioned u need Linux containers...so it has to be .net core.

Comment: Yes I need Linux Containers. Thanks for the answer.